# How to write a keyword in robot framework that uses AWS Signature in Authorization

Tags: amazon-web-services, api, robotframework

I want to write a request keyword in robot framework that uses AWS signature in authorization. I saw some tutorials in youtube but it is only for the Basic Auth and not AWS signature. AWS signature uses AccessKey and Secretkey.

does anyone tried creating a request keyword in robot framework for AWS signature? any help will be much appreciated. thanks!

[AWS Signature in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aITqX.png)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you follow the document of AWS Because they will tell you how to do this https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4-signed-request-examples.html.